# Why is it not possible to set a CSS variable in a:visited but in a:hover?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, chromium

Why do most modern browsers (except Firefox) not support setting a CSS variable in `a:visited`?

This is not working in Chromium based browsers, Safari, etc.:

```css
a:visited {
  --bg-color: red;
}
```

But all browsers support setting variables in `a:hover`:

```css
a:hover {
  --bg-color: red;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/mamiu/pen/YzvXXqw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tybo this doesn't work [for privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#privacy_restrictions).

The solution is to simply chain CSS selectors and to change the CSS properties directly instead of using variables.

```css
a:visited span.some-child-element {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I've also updated the demo: https://codepen.io/mamiu/pen/YzvXXqw

Answer (score 1):

Chrome disabled css for *:visited* unless its only for a color change.

Like so..

```
a { 
background-color: grey;
}

a:visited {
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GoodGrim! Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Just found it. Seems like this is disabled for privacy reasons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#privacy_restrictions

Comment: Exactly that privacy issues